# Markdown outline sync error in VS Code Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, markdown, outline

1. New markdown was created or modified, but it was not updated immediately. click online to refresh and update
2. If I click to change the markdown in the outline, it will change the markdown of the body. But If I change the markdown in the body, it will not be reflected in the outline. It will be updated only when I click outline to refresh it also

As you can see in the picture, "follow cursor" was checked
body-outline instant synchronization worked fine until about 3 weeks ago, but it's suddenly stopped working since recently

Please help me if you know the solution.

[image: VSC]

Answer (score 1):

This is a recent known issue. See https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/190631#issuecomment-1681430310. A fix seems to have been made in [`7b70717`](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/commit/7b707177921e2ee40ffcb277544673b16532806e), which is scheduled for release in the August 2023 milestone. Hold on tight a bit and wait for the fix to release.

For your reference / learning purposes, I found the above issue ticket by googling "`github vscode jupyter notebook issues "markdown" outline "bug"`", which led me to [Outline in jupyter notebook explorer does not update
#190715](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/190715), which is marked as a duplicate of #190631.